# Getting error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223BeanInfoSupport" in Jmeter-5.6.2 when adding "JSR233 Listener"

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I have the problem, after adding "JSR233 Listener" in Jmeter, i got the error "**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223BeanInfoSupport**", and already adding "**groovy-jsr233-3.0.19**" to directory **\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\lib\ext** but still got the same error.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. [JSR223BeanInfoSupport](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.6.2/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/util/JSR223BeanInfoSupport.java) class is a part of [ApacheJMeter_core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core/5.6.2), if you're getting a NoClassDefFoundError on a class which is from JMeter Core it means that your JMeter installation is broken.
2. JMeter 5.6.2 comes with [Groovy 3.0.17](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.6.2/src/bom-thirdparty/build.gradle.kts#L29) and `groovy-jsr223-3.0.17.jar` file needs to be present in **lib** folder of your JMeter installation, not in lib/ext which is for JMeter plugins. See [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) user manual entry for more details. If it's not there it means that your JMeter installation is broken.

The solution for both is [re-installing JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation) as there shouldn't be any problem with using JSR223 Listener in JMeter 5.6.2

[image]

Comment: Hi Mr. Dmitri, thank you for the advice, i'm already re-installing JMeter and it's worked, thanks for your help and support Mr. Dmitri.